# Parsing images in Json

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to parse Json data from this link [a link](https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json)

And I parse all of it but now I want to parse images. When I try to parse it I am parsing all images in the json, but I want just the image of the item.

This is my response code:

```
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray imageArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("im:image");
                    for (int j =0; j < imageArray.length(); j++) {
                        String image = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("im:image").getJSONObject(j).getString("label").toString();
                        ImagesModule imagesModule = new ImagesModule();
                        imagesModule.setImageUrl(image);
                        imagesModules.add(imagesModule);
                    }}
                imageRecyclerViewadapter = new ImageViewAdapter(imagesModules,getContext());
                AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageRecyclerViewadapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: I think that library SDWebImage (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) can help you to load images without any problems.

Comment: no thank u not like this i wont it like my code

Comment: I don't understand, after parsing the images in "imageArray" array, you are looping through the array which is correct but why are you fetching it from the main JSON, If i am not wrong, you can get the object directly from the  "imageArray" and you can get the image url easily. try in this way, I did not check whole of your code. I guess if you try the way i explained, you can find out the mistake if any there. Let me know if still you can't find the mistake.

Comment: did you mean like this ?? 
                            String image2 = imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("label").toString();

i try it and still same !

Comment: thank u i post my question here with full detail  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406698/parsing-data-from-json-as-a-collection-of-image-to-picasso/39406947?noredirect=1#comment66139330_39406947)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really understand if your one is the question or answer to the problem. But if you want parse it by url, instead ImageModule you can try and getting image by image also:

```
let img = UIImage()
if let url = NSURL(string: image) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        img = UIImage(data: data)!
        // array.append(img)
    }
}
```

That for iOS!

Comment: thank u i post my question here with full detail  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406698/parsing-data-from-json-as-a-collection-of-image-to-picasso/39406947?noredirect=1#comment66139330_39406947)

Comment: This question was actually Android

Comment: yep, but there was a tag for iOS before in the question)