# Parsing data from Json as a collection of image to Picasso

Tags: android, json

I tried to parse a collection of image to `recyclerview` as `gridview` using `Picasso` library but i cannot make it work

Note : i dont have any error but not working 
Here's Json data [a link](https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json)

My module

```
public class ImagesModule

{
 public ArrayList getListTest() {
    return listTest;
}

public void setListTest(ArrayList listTest) {
    this.listTest = listTest;
}

ArrayList listTest = new ArrayList( );

}
```

this is the Adapter`

```
public class ImageViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<ImagesModule> imagesModules;
Context context;

public ImageViewAdapter(List<ImagesModule> imagesModules, Context context){
    super();
    this.imagesModules = imagesModules;
    this.context = context;}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.imageitem, parent,false );
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( v );

    return viewHolder;}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ImagesModule imagesModule = imagesModules.get( position );
    Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(imagesModule.getListTest())).into(holder.appImage);}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imagesModules.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public android.widget.ImageView appImage;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        appImage = (android.widget.ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.imagegallary);
     }}}
```

and this is the fragment

```
public class ImageViewFragment extends Fragment {
List<ImagesModule> imagesModules;


List<ImagesModule> imagesModule;
RecyclerView AppRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter imageRecyclerViewadapter;
String jsonUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json";
RequestQueue requestQueue;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public ImageViewFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_view, container, false);
}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageRecyclerView);
    imagesModule = new ArrayList<>();
    imagesModules = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonAppShowData();
}
public void JsonAppShowData() {
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                ImagesModule imagesModule = new ImagesModule();

                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray imageArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("im:image");
                    for (int j =0; j < imageArray.length(); j++) {
                        ArrayList listTest = new ArrayList( );
                        String image = imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("label");
                        listTest.add(image);
                        imagesModule.setListTest(listTest);
                        imagesModules.add(imagesModule);}}

                imageRecyclerViewadapter = new ImageViewAdapter(imagesModules,getContext());
                AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageRecyclerViewadapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            }}}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e( "LOG", error.toString() );}});
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext().getApplicationContext(),3);
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a `List<String> imageUrls` to save urls to be viewed by picasso, no need for special object for that. To solve it, change your json parsing code to

```
try {
    JSONArray entries = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
    int count = entries.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        JSONObject imageJson = entries.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("im:image");
        // in case you want to get image with height 53
        String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("0").getString("label");

        // String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("1").getString("label"); height 75
        // String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("2").getString("label"); height 100

        // add urls to the list
        imageUrls.add(imageUrl);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then change your adapter to have a `List<String> imageUrls` instead of `List<ImagesModule> imagesModule` and pass the parsed list to the constructor. Finally in your adapter `onBindViewHolder()` change the picasso code to

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrls.get(position)).into(holder.appImage);
```

hope it helps

Comment: what u mean whith " entries" and json object json feed !Json array !!its true ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake when I edited the code. I updated the answer.

Comment: thank you 
i bot " List <ImagesModule> imagesModule;" in the try ! but 
how to declare imageUrls??

Comment: In your fragment a global variable `List<String> imageUrls;` and in `onCreateView()` initialize it `imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: its not working !! i think because we not send the list to the module then to the Adapter on the Picasso i try to send it but Picasso have error !

Comment: Don't add the whole images to a single module and try to view it. Make another module of single url and send the list of new modules to the adapter.

Comment: i dont understand what exactly you mean ! discrbe more i know that i Bothered you iam sorry :)

Comment: this is the qustion with all details plz if you have any idea try to answer 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429158/parsing-jsonarray-to-picasso-library)

Comment: can you explain to me this ? 
then change your adapter to have a List<String> imageUrls instead of List<ImagesModule> imagesModule ???????

Answer (score 0):

You can't load multiple images in single `ImageView` so try to load each image in different `ImageView`, As I have observerd there are fixed 3 number of images in each module so add 3 `ImageViews` in your xml layout and apply images separately.

Comment: but this is a recycler view and i can do it ,, but the problem is load all of the image in the json or load one json ! i need to load 3 image because in the Json array are 3 link of image :) thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Yes in `recycler view's item xml` you need to add 3 `ImageViews`. and load images into that in `onBindViewHolder()` separately. Has your problem solved?

Comment: each `url` in the `list` should be loaded in different `ImageView`

Comment: thank you but this will not working becuse i wont it by parsing json in the list :)

Comment: I think you are lagging basics. so please look into basics