# How to parse image from jsonarray and display using Picasso

Tags: android, json, picasso

I have this [JSON data](https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json)

I have to parse the `JSONArray` that with key "im:image" that has 3 links of image and display it using Picasso library.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i clarify my question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429158/parsing-jsonarray-to-picasso-library) 
if you wont to answer me !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonFeed = new JSONObject(your_original_json).getJSONObject("feed");
    JSONArray entries = jsonFeed.getJSONArray("entry");
    int count = entries.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        JSONObject imageJson = entries.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("im:image");
        // in case you want to get image with height 53
        String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("0").getString("label");

        // String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("1").getString("label"); height 75
        // String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("2").getString("label"); height 100
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(imageView);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thank u but what you mean ? "your_original_json"

Comment: You're welcome. It's the long json string in url.

Comment: its not working ? !! :(

Comment: this is the full code if you it and iam tried many time but its still not working  :) 

[Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406698/parsing-data-from-json-as-a-collection-of-image-to-picasso/39406947?noredirect=1#comment66139330_39406947)

Comment: Did you get an exception or you tried to load all images in the same `ImageView` or what? How did you use it?

Comment: no i dont get exceptions but the images its not loaded ! yes i tried to load to the same ImageView ,, plases check this link 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406698/parsing-data-from-json-as-a-collection-of-image-to-picasso/39406947?noredirect=1#comment66139330_39406947)

Comment: You misunderstood few things. First, they give you the same image with different sizes so that you load the suitable one "not the 3". Second, The adapter should contain a `List<String> imageUrls` that refer to all the urls in the url not list list of object that has an array list. I'll check the other question and try to answer it.

Comment: thank u i will try this things and i hope you to answer me :)  thank u very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123054/discussion-between-moayed-ayasaa-and-santorian).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HttpClient to get Json from your URL. Code below.

```
 try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream weps = entity.getContent();
            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(weps, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                weps.close();
                result = sb.toString();//result string defined above will store your json.

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Coverting result" + e.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Http connection" + e.toString());
            }

        try {

            JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(result);
            int count = entries.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            JSONObject imageJson= entries.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("im:image");
            // in case you want to get image with height 53
            String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("0").getString("label");

            // String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("1").getString("label"); height 75
            // String imageUrl = imageJson.getJSONObject("2").getString("label"); height 100
            Picasso.with(context)//context variable of the class
            .load(imageUrl)// url from Json
            .into(imageView); //your image view object
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Dataaaa" + e.toString());

        }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but how i can use this here ? 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406698/parsing-data-from-json-as-a-collection-of-image-to-picasso/39406947?noredirect=1#comment66139330_39406947)